# Checking if a scipy sparse matrix is CSC or CSR

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I would like to know the best way to check if a scipy sparse matrix, if CSC or CSR. Right now I'm using.

```
rows, cols = X.shape()
indptr = X.indptr()
if len(indptr) == cols + 1:
    print "csc"
else:
    print "csr"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like you could use the `.getformat()` method:

```
>>> m0 = scipy.sparse.csc_matrix([1])
>>> m0.getformat()
'csc'
>>> m1 = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix([1])
>>> m1.getformat()
'csr'
```

Comment: Thanks. Should look at the docs much closer next time, before posting.

Answer (score 1):

You could check the class

```
m0=sparse.csc_matrix([1])

In [4]: type(m0).__name__
Out[4]: 'csc_matrix'
In [5]: isinstance(m0,sparse.csc_matrix)
Out[5]: True

In [6]: isinstance(m0,sparse.csr_matrix)
Out[6]: False

In [9]: sparse.isspmatrix_csc(m0)
Out[9]: True

In [10]: sparse.isspmatrix_csc??
...
def isspmatrix_csc(x):
    return isinstance(x, csc_matrix)
```